# Change structure of a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have this object structure:

```
"users": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "supplier_name": [
                "Supplier1"
            ],
            "supplier_code": "SUP001",
            "count": "21"
        }
}
```

I'd like to change it so it appears like this:

```
"users": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "suppliers":[
                {
                    "supplier_id": 1,
                    "supplier_name": [
                        "Supplier1"
                    ]
                }    
            ],
            "supplier_code": "SUP001",
            "count": "21"
        }
}
```

I tried this hoping it would work:

```
const group = accumulator[item.id];
  group.suppliers = [];
  group.suppliers = group.suppliers.push(item.supplier_name, item.supplier_id, item.supplier_code);
  return accumulator;
```

Unfortunately that just seems to give me a count of the objects pushed into `suppliers`, `suppliers` isn't an array and `supplier_id`, `supplier_name` and `supplier_code` are still visible outside of `suppliers`:

```
"users": {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John",
            "email": "john@doe.com",
            "supplier_id": 1,
            "supplier_name": [
                "Supplier1"
            ],
            "supplier_code": "SUP001",
            "count": "21",
            "suppliers: 3
        }
}
```

How do I change it to the format I want?

Comment: `.push` mutates the original object and returns its new length, hence you don't need the assignment statement and can simply do: `group.suppliers.push(item.supplier_name, item.supplier_id, item.supplier_code);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use es6 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) es2017 (or [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) instead).
If you assume that `users` contains more then one user you could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

In the example below original object won't be mutated.

Hope it helps

```js
const original = {
  "users": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "email": "john@doe.com",
      "supplier_id": 1,
      "supplier_name": [
          "Supplier1"
      ],
      "supplier_code": "SUP001",
      "count": "21"
    }
  } 
};

const { users } = original;

const reshaped = Object.values(users).reduce((acc, { id, supplier_id, supplier_name, ...rest }) => {
  acc[id] = {
    ...rest,
    suppliers: [{
      supplier_id,
      supplier_name: [supplier_name]
    }]
  };
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reshaped);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `object` to push into the `suppliers` array. Also, delete the old keys which are not needed.

**Edit -** You can directly create an array of 1 object. Thanks @Adam

```
const group = accumulator[item.id];
group.suppliers = [{
    supplier_id: item.supplier_id,
    supplier_name: item.supplier_name,
    supplier_code: item.supplier_code
}];

delete group.supplier_id;
delete group.supplier_name;
delete group.supplier_code;
return accumulator;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick and modern solution:

```
const parseUsers = (users) => {
    let parsedUsers = {};
    for (key in users) {
        const user = users[key];
        // destructuring (or extracting) the relevant keys from the . user object, keeping everything else under 'rest'
        const { supplier_id, supplier_name, ...rest } = user; 
        parsedUsers[key] = {
            ...rest, // spreading back our rest params
            suppliers: [ // creating a new array and populating it with the keys which we previously extracted (along with their corresponding values)
                supplier_id,
                supplier_name
            ]
        }
    }

    return parsedUsers;
}
```

usage: `parseUsers(json.users)`